# include dojo toolkit in appcelerator titanium

Tags: dojo, titanium

I want to use dojoToolkit in my project. But when I include it with Ti.include('dojo/dojo/dojo.js') I have got a error message "defineAlreadyDefined". Titanium has method called define in global namespace and there is method with similar name in dojo. Also there are some other methods with similar names (for example, required). How can I use it?

P.S. I build my project for web

Answer (score 1):

Dojo as is will not work in Titanium. Dojo is a browser toolkit, not a mobile toolkit, it accesses things that are only for the web.

[But, this guy ported it over to work with titanium, try it instead.](https://github.com/aehlke/titanium-dojo)

Comment: I build my project for web

Comment: Then why don't you just use Dojo. What do you need from Dojo exactly that titanium does not provide or vice versa?

Comment: I want to create complex class hierarchy and I think dojo is great way for it